# Ants carrying metal scew

Tags: ant

Today I saw a few ants carrying a metal screw with them.

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz3AW.jpg)

What might be the reason behind this?  (nesting material?)

Comment: Is there any reason why they *shouldn't* be doing that?

Comment: I think the question is reasonable - this seems like very unusual behaviour. Perhaps there was organic material (food stuff) in the threads of the screw and they assumed it was wholly made of food.

Comment: Damn. It's just fascinating watching them cooperate like that. From the way they are sometimes stumble from lack of perfect coordination, they could probably carry it with fewer ants than there are. If you see a bunch of humans moving a couch, if we stumble like that the entire couch falls so those ants are working below capacity I think.

Comment: +1 for the video. Maybe they're building something. If so, please post the video of them using the screwdriver, which ought to be even more fascinating.

Comment: ants use the materials avaliable to them it is why you can find glass plastics and other non natural building materials in many ant hills.

Comment: How can you be sure the screw was made of metal?